# can ipython parallel operate across different sets of nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

With N=P+Q compute nodes, can ipython send a message to the distinct R nodes and Q nodes at the same time and for each set of nodes to do some computation in parallel and for both set of nodes to return the result to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming direct view

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
c = Client()
c.ids
c[:].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello, World")
```

result in

```
['Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World']
```

Partitionning on even/odd engines

```
(
c[0::2].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello"),
c[1::2].apply_sync(lambda : "World")
)
```

result in

```
(['Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Hello'], ['World', 'World', 'World', 'World'])
```

here I apply sync, so it's not exactly at the same time, but if you apply async, you can collect at once after.

You can also push a variable on each set of node that will "decide" which computation to do.

Comment: brill! thank-you. just asked another related question.